# Access file on a Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

If you are familiar with NowJS, one you start an instance of Now on the server, you can access  a file located on the server by `<script src="http://localhost:8080/nowjs/now.js"></script>`

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 2):

There are many static file handler modules already in node, take a look at:
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-web-frameworks-static

Most popular are:
https://github.com/felixge/node-paperboy
and
https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static

Using node static is as simple as:

```
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new(static.Server)('./public');

    require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
        request.addListener('end', function () {

            file.serve(request, response);
        });
    }).listen(8080);
```